# Multiple Jasper reports - Single request

Tags: jasper-reports, zip

I have a requirement,where I can select multiple records,and choose the action to generate zipped report with document each(pdf in my case) for each of the selected entries.
For example Employee1,Employee2,Employee3 would be selected,and when I choose to generate report,3 reports should be generated one each for the employee,and the output has to be zipped and downloaded.

For now what I do is generate the jasperPrint and export the report to ZipOutputstream with a new zipentry for each of the employee.
This means running the queries thrice and adding the outputstream to zip.

Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is normally the correct way, the alternatives are if you need to avoid multiple queries.

1. Load all you data in to a `List<Employee>` pass a `new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(List<Employee>)` for each Employee. (This decrease queries but increase memory usage).
2. If you have control of the pages (example 1 employee per page), you can generate 1 pdf with all employees and then use [itext](/questions/tagged/itext) to split it in multiple pdf.

   ```
   PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("nameOfReport.pdf");
   int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
   int i = 0;            
   while ( i < n ) {
       Document document = new Document(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
       PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream("Employee_" + i + ".pdf"));
       document.open();
       PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, ++i);
       writer.addPage(page);
       document.close();
       writer.close();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Petter.Option1 helped.